# How to stop TDDium from running script/cucumber features automatically

Tags: ruby, rspec, continuous-integration, cucumber, integration-testing

I am using [TDDium](http://tddium.com) to run my tests continuously.

Every time I push something it runs using my `tddium.yml` configuration file:

```
:tddium:
  :timeout: 90
  :postgresql: false
  :test_pattern:                                
    - spec/**_spec.rb        

  :mysql: 
    :adapter: mysql2
    :config:
      :adapter: mysql2
      :database: <%= ENV['TDDIUM_DB_NAME'] %>
      :username: <%= ENV['TDDIUM_DB_USER'] %>
      :password: <%= ENV['TDDIUM_DB_PASSWORD'] %>
      :database: <%= ENV['TDDIUM_DB_NAME'] %>
```

As you can see, I'm specifying `:test_pattern:`.

Even though I have a set of `.feature` files in my `features` directory, I don't want it to run them automatically.

How do I stop `TDDium` from doing this?

I thought that by specifying `:test_pattern:` and not including the `.feature` pattern it'd skip them.

I've tried running `tddium suite --edit` and this is what happened:

```
bonsai-2 project$ tddium suite --edit
... Detected ruby ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin11.4.2]
... Detected bundle Bundler version 1.3.5
... Detected gem 1.8.24
... Configured test pattern from tddium.yml:

 - spec/**_spec.rb

>>> To change the pattern:
    1. Edit tddium.yml
    2. Run `tddium suite --edit` again.

>>> To set up Hosted CI, enter a git URL to pull from. 
    You can also set a git URL to push to after tests pass.

>>> Set both pull and push URLs to 'disable' to disable hosted CI completely.

Enter git URL to pull from (default 'ssh://git@github.com/etagwerker/project.git') or enter 'disable': 
Enter git URL to push to (default '') or enter 'disable': disable
Custom Campfire room for this suite (current: '') or enter 'disable': disable
Custom HipChat room for this suite (current: '') or enter 'disable': At Work
Updated suite successfully.
```

Any other ideas would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest disabling Tddium’s automatic test mapping (i.e. set :test_pattern to none)

```
:tddium:
   :test_pattern: 'none'
```

Then you can manually invoke the tests through the :tests configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you have never run the test suite for your current branch, Tddium will simply pick up the test pattern and use it.  If you have already configured the suite for the current branch, the simplest solution is to run `tddium suite --edit`.

Comment: I had already ran the test suite. I've tried what you suggested but it didn't solve my problem. It still tries to run `script/cucumber features`. I've updated my question with the result.